# SharePoint 2013 site collection backup failed with logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, backup

I am taking a site collection backup using standard SharePoint PowerShell command "Backup-SPSite" and it is failed with below error. I am using SharePoint 2013.

> PS C:\Users\SPFarm> Backup-SPSite "http://SPVM/sites/SCURL"  -Path
> C:\ContentDBs\SCbackup.bak Backup-SPSite : SQL Server detected a
> logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected
> 1:589190; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read of page (1:589190) in
> database ID 8 at offset 0x0000011fb0c000 in file
> 'E:\MSSQL12.POWERPIVOT\MSSQL\DATA\WSS_Content.mdf'.  Additional
> messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide
> more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database
> integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database
> consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many
> factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online. At line:1
> char:1 + Backup-SPSite "http://SPVM/sites/SCURL"

I ran "DBCC CHECKDB with data_purity" command using SQL Management Studio and found below errors.

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 3177 consistency errors in
> database 'WSS_Content'. repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair
> level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (WSS_Content).

To resolve this error, I ran below commands using SQL Management Studio.

> alter database WSS_Content SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
> DBCC CHECKDB (WSS_Content,REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) alter database
> WSS_Content SET MULTI_USER

Now, most of the errors are cleared but still 51 errors present and all errors are as same as below.

> Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Table error: Object ID 885578193,
> index ID 1, partition ID 72057594143178752, alloc unit ID
> 72057594175422464 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page
> (1:589190), slot 7, text ID 49327767552 is referenced by page
> (1:6688), slot 1, but was not seen in the scan.
> Could not repair this error.

As it is saying "Could not repair this error", what can be done to resolve this error to take the site collection backup? Please note that I do not have any good backup that I can use to restore so I need to fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to restore the database from a known good backup. REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS is not a supported operation on a SharePoint database.

See [Support for changes to the databases that are used by Office server products and by Windows SharePoint Services](https://support.microsoft.com/topic/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-products-and-by-windows-sharepoint-services-502c6da1-be7e-39b0-0ea8-8b4ebd44a374)